# My top toolbar scroll togather Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I follow the example by angular in codepen .

But my problem , my toolbar still scroll and  whole page still can scroll when sidebar opened.

here my code

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <md-toolbar layout="row" class="top-bar">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
                <span class="burger-lines"></span>
            </md-button>
            <h1><span ng-bind="title"></span></h1>
            <span flex></span>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div ng-include="'views/sidebar.html'"></div>
    <div layout="row" flex>

            <div layout="column" flex ng-view=""></div>

    </div>
```

sidebar.html

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
    <md-toolbar class="top-bar">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout-padding ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">
        <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
            Close Sidenav Left
        </md-button>
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

Comment: What is inside of sidebar.html? Why do you have two nested divs with different layouts in the end? Where is your md-content?

Comment: @LionC update my question . Is it because i dont have md-content? Thanks . md-content the problem